# Overflow on windows resize

Tags: jquery, ajax, resize, window, overflow

Hi this might sound to be novice but i am not able to figure out the solution to this simple problem.

1. On window resize i want all the elements as it is on the page as they were when the widow was in maximized state.When the user resizes window all the content exceeding the view port i.e visible area should simply be hidden.

I have tried `$(document).css('overflow','hidden')` but does not seems to solve the problem.

further, out of the technologies being talked about in reference to the ajax push technology which technology seems to be useful to work on long term.for ex out of comet,long polling, pubhubsubbub or XMPP. the answer should be based on the availability of open source tools and how active is the community.

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: A) You shouldn't combine two completely unrelated problems into one question B) Can you explain you first problem better. What are you trying to achieve? Which "problem" does `$(document).css('overflow','hidden')` not solve?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.If u have ever try to resize big sites like facebook,twitter any big site for that matter u can clearly see none of their divs or elements moving and changing there position.I hope i make myself clear.I tried accomplishing this using the jquery code but still "this problem of moving divs on resize" persists.

Comment: And thanks for ur suggestion. I will keep that in mind next time.btw do you know the answer for ajax push part?

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Depending on your needs, maybe you want to set the width also.